# query calculation error

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I've seen some errors in my life, but this one caught me by surprise the most.

I have a float column containing `0.02`.

Now i'm trying this query :

```
select rma.*,120.0/60.0*rma.amount as reward
```

Now math tells us the result will be `0.04`,
But suprisingly enough MySql (Version 5.5.28) claims otherwise, and says it's :

```
0.03999999910593033
```

I've also tried without the `.0` with the numbers, and using braces, still same result.

Now the same results happens with all cases of uneven numbers. for example `4.1` will be `8.199999809265137`

Anyone knows why that happens?

Comment: What happens if you just type "Select 120.0/60.0*0.02"?

Comment: @Love2Learn it gives the right result.

Comment: When you say the column contains 0.02 are you sure that is the value or could it possibly be a rounded representation of the actual number stored? Is the column itself a calculated value?

Comment: It's ok the answers below both solved and explain the problem. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `CAST` it like so:

```
select rma.*, CAST((120.0 / 60.0 * rma.amount) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as reward
```

Comment: Well that did solve it. Any idea why that happend? why do you have to cast it? can you provide a short explination please.

Comment: @eric.itzhak - I am not sure how MySQL treats a new created column from a multiplied columns, it seems that it doesn't perceive a specific precision for it. So `DECIMAL(10, 2)` will give you in two digit precision.